# In log4j2 how do I log everything into a file and additionally into a different file based on whether a context map variable is set or not?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I would like to log everything into a file named `application.log`. Additionally if I set `ThreadContext.put("logFileName", "somethingElse.log");` I would like the log entries to also go to `somethingElse.log` (`application.log` should still be filled with all entries). If I unset the `logFileName` variable in Java code then log4j2 should stop logging into `somethingElse.log` but log into `differentFile.log` if I set `logFileName` to that name.

My current configuration does what I need but the last route in it seems like an overkill because I basically need to ignore everything via regular expression.

**Any ideas for a simpler configuration?**

```
<Configuration name="application">
  <Properties>
    <property name="fileLayout">%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p - %m%n
    </property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="File" fileName="logs/application.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${fileLayout}" />
    </File>
    <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${ctx:logFileName}">
        <Route>
          <File name="File" fileName="logs/${ctx:logFileName}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${fileLayout}" />
          </File>
        </Route>

        <Route key="$${ctx:logFileName}">
          <File name="Ignore" fileName="logs/application.log">
            <RegexFilter regex=".*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="DENY"/>
          </File>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
      <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>     
</Configuration>
```

Comment: ey Tony, i don't have any clue about how to archieve it by programing it directly into java. But if you are launching you app using a *Unix OS, you could employ the command https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command), that will help you to archive what are you looking for. Is only a tip.... hope it helps.

Comment: This app runs on both Windows and Unix OS types. Additionally `tee` would not react to a variable set inside the code so your tip won't help.

Comment: Sorry Tony... at least i tried it.